# Why is BETWEEN significantly slower than running each query separately?

Tags: mysql, sql

**Update**: sorry folks, after using `explain` it looks like this question is too localized. The answer was that mysql was choosing the wrong index. Voting to close.

I ran a job like

```
select * from some_table where sql_date = '2011-12-01';
```

and it ran in 30 minutes.

Now I'm running

```
select * from some_table where sql_date BETWEEN '2011-12-01' and '2011-12-08';
```

and it is taking 20+ hours, which makes me think that it would have been faster to run

```
select * from some_table where sql_date = '2011-12-01';
select * from some_table where sql_date = '2011-12-02';
select * from some_table where sql_date = '2011-12-03';
```

etc. Why is 'BETWEEN' so slow?

Update:

@loganfsmyth: there is an index on the date.

@Magnus: several joins on big tables.

@Sparky: no binary data and I'm using `INTO OUTFILE 'filename.txt'`.

Explain returns this for a single date:

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                  | key                                                       | key_len | ref                                      | rows    | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dates      | ref    | PRIMARY,index_dates_on_sql_date                                                                         | index_dates_on_sql_date                            | 3       | const                                    |       1 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | views      | ref    | index_views_doc_id,index_views_id | index_new_views_id | 8       | olap.dates.date_key,const         | 3241236 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | docs       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,pub_date,published_id,user_id,user_anonymous,user_deleted                      | PRIMARY                                                   | 4       | olap.views.doc_id       |       1 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | docs_count | ref    | user_id                                                                                                   | user_id                                              | 5       | slave.docs.user_id |       1 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What is the type of the date column?

Comment: Do you have an index on the `date` column?

Comment: 20h hours for a simple query like that?! What kind of monster table do you have?

Comment: You're wrong. A sample size of one date isn't enough to estimate how long running each individually would take. Try running those 9 queries individually and see how long it takes.

Comment: Is there some sort of binary data or blob field?  Try changing the * to a single field, if that runs quickly, it is probably IO with the amount of data coming back.   If a single field runs slowly too, check out the indexes.

Comment: You don't have a simple `SELECT * FROM Table`. You have some sort of join between 4 tables and possibly some `GROUP BY` or/and `DISTINCT` or/and `ORDER BY` there.

Comment: And 20+ hours is not slow. When a complex query for a single date takes 30 minutes (that is slow), then for 8 dates, it can take 2x time or 8x time or 64x time. Calculating `30m x 64 = 30 hours`, so that's expected.

Answer (score 1):

With a 20+ hour running time, I'd suspect you're doing a table scan for the BETWEEN query.  Possibly not for the singleton query.

You should ask MySQL what it's doing.  Run

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE date BETWEEN '2011-12-01' AND '2011-12-08';
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE date = '2011-12-01';
```

and compare the results.  Is one using an index while the other isn't?

Answer (score 1):

Put the keyword explain before the queries

e.g.

```
Explain select * from some_table where date = '2011-12-01'
```

It will tell you what it's doing, edit you post with the results for a question we will be better able to answer.

I could guess and it might be right, there again I might not